# Python: Pandas Dataframe select and multiply element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following problem:

starting situation:
-data frame with several columns
-one column contains only integers

desired result
- same data frame but in the specific column all numbers that are smaller then 10 have been multiplied by 10

What i came up with so far:

```
selection = data['column_name'].loc[(data['column_name'] < 10)] 
for i[0] in selection:
 data['column_name'].replace(i[1]*10)
```

this ofcourse does not work, since the from loc returned object is somehow no list or data frame but contains the index and value of the selected elements

i would really appreciate an easy solution

Comment: Try this `data.loc[data['column_name'] < 10, 'column_name'] *= 10 `

Comment: You can also try this `df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].clip(lower=10)`

Comment: thank you this works like a charm